# Tab 2 Guest user problem

Tags: security

Hacker installed malware in Galaxy Tab (6 6.0.1) and disabled switching into Guest user. How do I remove this. I have run every kind of removal tool I can think of and every scan comes up clean.

Note: I am not a tech savy user

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed some Antivirus on your phone and they didn't work, try to do a reset of your phone and if it doesn't work try a hardreset. I hope I helped you, let me know if it worked